# jquery plugin: how to return default value when some options are not set?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, extend, jquery-1.9

I can't figure out what I have done wrong in this plugin,

```
(function($){

    var methods = {

        defaults: function(options) {

            // Default options.
            var defaults = {
                setup: {
                    tester1: "hello1",
                    tester2: "hello2",
                    tester3: "hello3"
                },
                tester: "hello world"               
            }

            // Always leave this line here.
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            alert(options.setup.tester2);

            // Return the processed options.
            return options;

        },

        init : function( options ) {

            var $this = this;
            var o = $this.plugin('defaults',options);

        },

        something : function( options ) {


        }
    };

    $.fn.plugin = function( method ) {

        // @reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );  // always change 'init' to something else if you different method name.
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.plugin' );
        }

        return this; 

    };

})(jQuery);
```

So,

```
jQuery().plugin(); // return 'hello2' --> correct
```

But,

```
jQuery().plugin({setup:{tester1:"x"}}); // return 'undefined' --> should be 'hello2'
```

Any ideas what should I do or what have I missed?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWZWG/)

Answer (score 1):

I use this codes to define defaults and options and it works:

```
var defaults = {
    speed : 150 ,
    check_effect: "fade" ,
    uncheck_effect: "fade" ,
    };

var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
```

And I dont use function on defining defaults like what you have!

Comment: but you have to use lines 9-21 (in previous fiddle) inside your $.fn.plugin like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BWZWG/7/

Comment: thanks for the help. but it is not what i need as in that way I cannot pass any options into `init` and other methods. take a look at my test - http://jsfiddle.net/BWZWG/8/

Comment: why you dont bring methods inside $.fn.plugin? take a look http://jsfiddle.net/BWZWG/10/

Comment: that works! I never knew that we can do that. I was following the format/ structure from jquery website.

Comment: we should inform this `bug` to jquery for misleading! :)

Comment: no, I think jquery is correct. take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/BWZWG/11/ I should get`x` as the answer, but `hello1` which is incorrect.

Comment: I think that is a plugin problem.because i always get the option (if it is set) by this way!

Comment: I think I got the solution from jqeury website. have a look at my answer below. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is,

```
var options = $.extend( true, {}, defaults, options );
```